# What am I supposed to do with the Backplanes for the PCA85276?

Tags: pcb-design, schematics

I am trying to use eight 14-segment display with this driver but I can't figure out what the backplanes would be for and what I should connect them to. It gives me this table with the possible configuration

[image: Table]

It then says that "The possible display configurations of the PCA85276 depend on the number of active backplane outputs required".

Would that mean that I would leave the pins floating/unconnected?

Here are the links to the data sheets:

- https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Varitronix%20PDFs/VIM-878.pdf
- https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA85276.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your display has a total of 128 segments (14 plus 2 per digit, 8 digits) so you'll need to have all four backplane outputs active as per the table:

[image]

The diagram just below that table in the datasheet shows you how to connect the display to the driver:

[image]

Your four backplane outputs (BP0 to BP3) should be connected to the four common pins of the display (COM0 to COM3) and 32 of the 40 segment outputs should be connected to the 32 remaining segment pins.